# Check for line in CSV, if not existant - append the line

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, csv

I have the following problem.

I am trying to match all existing rows of a CSV file with the current one.

If the line already exists, the script should only show me it exists.
If the row does not exist, the script should tell me that the row does not exist.

However, the script always tells me that the row does not exist, even though I have checked that the row does exist.

Here is my Code so far:

```
# Imports from Library(s)
from pathlib import Path
import csv
from windows_tools.installed_software import get_installed_software

# Check if the csv file exists - if not: create it
path = Path('./programms.csv')
existingFile = []
if path.is_file() is not True:
    with open('programms.csv', 'w', newline='') as write1:
        w_object = csv.writer(write1)
        w_object.writerow(["Name", "Version", "Publisher"])
        write1.close()

# Lists all Software on the computer
for software in get_installed_software():
    csv_list = (software['name'], software['version'], software['publisher'])
    
    with open('programms.csv', 'r') as f1:
        existingFile = [line for line in csv.reader(f1, delimiter=',')]
    f1.close()

    #Checks if 
    if csv_list in existingFile:
        print(str(csv_list) + "already is in the list") 
        continue

    if csv_list not in existingFile:
        print("Current Object is not in the Existing lines")

    #     # Open our existing CSV file in append mode
    #     # Create a file object for this file
    #     with open('programms.csv', 'a', newline='') as append1:


    #     # Pass this file object to csv.writer() and create writer_object
    #         writer_object = csv.writer(append1)
        
    #         # Pass the list as an argument intothe writerow() 
    #         writer_object.writerow(csv_list)
    #         # Close the file object
    #         append1.close()
            
print (existingFile)
```

I already tried to specify the types i want to check it with:
`if str(csv_list) in list(existingFile):`
Sadly im just starting with python and I'm not quite sure how to tackle this one.

Comment: Try `csv_list = [software['name'], software['version'], software['publisher']]`

Comment: You don't need to call `close()` when you use `with` to open the file. The main feature of the context manager is that it closes the file automatically.

Comment: You're setting `csv_list` to a tuple, not a list because you're using `()` instead of `[]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to you I fixed it!

> Try csv_list = [software['name'], software['version'], software['publisher']] –
> inspectorG4dget

and

> You're setting csv_list to a tuple, not a list because you're using () instead of [] –
> Barmar

were right! I just changed the tuple to a list and that was it.
Thanks to all that replied so quickly!

Best Regards

Pr3adus

Comment: Simply reply the answer that solved your problem instead of creating another answer. Also, mark the answer that solved your problem as the solution.

Comment: I tried to mark the comment as solution but couldn't find a way to mark it.

Comment: You’ve done that already.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can check if a list is in a csv (converted into list of lists)
Note that Python returns false for: "1" == 1
You will need to make sure types match in the csv and the list you want to check

```
import csv

'''
test.csv:"
1,2,3,4,5
2,3,4,5,6
3,4,5,6,7
4,5,6,7,8
"
'''
with open('test.csv', 'r') as f:
  
    # Return a reader object which will
    # iterate over lines in the given csvfile
    csv_reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
  
    # convert string to list
    list_of_csv = list(csv_reader)
  
    print(list_of_csv)

test = [1,2,3,4,5]
if test in list_of_csv:
    print("IS IN LIST")
else:
    print("NOT IN LIST")
#The above will print NOT IN LIST because the test list is a list of ints, and the csv list is a list of strings

test2 = ["1","2","3","4","5"]
if test2 in list_of_csv:
    print("IS IN LIST")
else:
    print("NOT IN LIST")
#Above will print IS IN LIST because the list has strings in it not ints
```